# Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'bias/Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?,)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement NEAT using tensorflow and I need to set the bias input to one using a placeholder(the bias has variable size, aka for each input in the batch), and I use tf.add_n to sum all neuron outputs, which needs my bias to have the same size as each neuron, each neuron(input, output and hidden) being of shape [None,]. But whenever I pass the feed_dict with:

```
feed_dict.update({
   self._bias: np.ones(100)
})
```

I always get the error in the title:

```
Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'bias/Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?,)'
```

Here is the code where i declare the placeholders:

```
self.input_nodes = inputs
self.output_nodes = outputs
self.node_evals = node_evals
self.activation = activation
self.nodes = {}

for i in self.input_nodes:
  with tf.name_scope('input_' + str(i)) as scope:
    self.nodes[i] = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, ])
if bias:
  with tf.name_scope('bias') as scope:
    self.nodes[len(self.input_nodes)] = \
        tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, ])
    self._bias = self.nodes[len(self.input_nodes)]
```

Here is the code where I create the feed_dict, self._inputts are the placeholders, inputs is an ndarray of shape [100, 2], _labels are the placeholders for the labels and labels is of shape [100, 1]:

```
feed_dict = {
  self._inputs[k]: inputs[:, k]
  for k in range(0, len(inputs[0]))
}
feed_dict.update({
  _labels[k]: labels[:, k]
  for k
    in range(0, len(labels[0]))
})
feed_dict.update({
  self._bias: np.ones(100)
})
```

What can I do?

Comment: You're feeding scalars to Tensorflow. where it expects a vector Try printing the tensors to see if the sizes are what you expect

Comment: I have tried printing the numpy shapes before assigning them and they are the correct shape. Tried using inputs of size [None, 1], but then it rises the a similar error: Cannot feed value of shape (100,) for Tensor 'bias/Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?,1)'. The numpy shapes are equal for all inputs and bias; and I can't check the tensors since it throws the error when feeding the dictionary.